# Using the .Switch command with sharpSvn not a valid path c#

Tags: c#, sharpsvn

I m using the sharpsvn library and I want to do a switch but it keeps giving me following error:

> *"This argument is not a valid path. A Uri was specified."*

I checked if the path was oke and the paths are good any Idea whats wrong?

```
var configpath2 = "http://website.com/svn/CMS/trunk/Configuration";

teststring = localpath + @"\trunk\Configuration\CMS";
svnClient.Switch(new Uri(teststring).ToString(), new SvnUriTarget(new Uri(configpath2)));
```

Comment: What does `localpath` contain? And where the exception is thrown, on `teststring` or `configpath2` ?

Comment: localpath is my local folder where trunk is located.
Its thrown in the end of the function.

Comment: End of which function? Show the last statement of that function

Comment: svnClient.Switch(new Uri(teststring).ToString(), new SvnUriTarget(new Uri(configpath2)))*Here is the error thrown*;

Answer (score 2):

Some related links:

1. http://docs.sharpsvn.net/current/html/M_SharpSvn_SvnClient_Switch_1.htm
2. http://docs.sharpsvn.net/current/html/Overload_SharpSvn_SvnClient_Switch.htm

As i understood by reading the above mentioned pages, is that you have to pass `string` as the first argument of `Switch`. Try this one:

```
svnClient.Switch(teststring, new SvnUriTarget(new Uri(configpath2)));
```

Comment: I tried that doesn`t work it stays the same message. A working example would be nice but can't find one online.

Comment: @Trustos Perhaps have a look at the [SwitchTests](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/svn/sharpsvn/trunk/src/SharpSvn.Tests/Commands/SwitchTests.cs) for some working examples (username guest, no password). Switch expects two parameters, the first is the path to the working copy that should be switched. The second is the Uri of the new location to switch to. So not only should the first parameter be of type `System.String`, it should be a valid path on your computer.

Comment: I come to a page where I am supposed to login.